# How to connect to dockerized database from outside of the docker network on local machine

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, networking

I have created this docker container for my postgres database on my windows machine:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --rm --name pg_container -v C:\pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data --env-file ./database.env postgres:latest
```

And if I run `docker exec -it pg_container bash` and run `psql` command I can create a database name `mydb` (in the real situation, this is being created by a flask application).

If I run

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' tma_pg_db_container
```

I will get `172.0.0.2`

Now I want to connect directly to the database from outside of the container.

`psql postgresql://postgres:<PASSWORD>@<IP_ADDRESS>:5432/tma_pg_db`

What should I use for `IP_ADDRESS`?

**Please note that I have another psotgres database created on the system level and not in the container. For that one, I use localhost it, and works fine, it connects.
If I use localhost, it connects to the system-level database not the container inside the docker container.**

Comment: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Please note that I have another psotgres database created on the system level and not in the container. For that one, I use localhost it and works fine, it connects.

Comment: You'll have to change the port number for your container, say `-p 5433:5432`. Then connect with localhost:5433.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `localhost`.  That will connect to the port you published using the `docker run -p` option.

(If you are using a VM-based solution like Docker Machine or Docker Toolbox, you need its IP address instead; `docker-machine ip` will tell you what it is.  If you're calling from a different host, use the physical host's IP address, the same way you would if the service wasn't running in a container.)

The two important corollaries to this are that (a) you don't need debugging tools like `docker exec` to interact with your database; and (b) you don't need to look up the `docker inspect` IP address (which also doesn't work in many common contexts).

Comment: I have another psotgres database created on the system level and not in the container. For that one, I use localhost and works fine

Comment: I added this information to the questions